# self-teach: In what order should I structure my studies?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, self-learning

I'm a 19 year old, who will be 20 in may.

I didn't go to the greatest high school, and I didn't get the proper education to prepare me for college.

I need to make a study plan for myself to truly learn and understand what I will need to complete a degree in Computer Science.

My studies will start with algebra. My plan so far looks like:

Algebra -- > Trig --> Pre-cal -- > cal1-3 (will try to teach myself Mechanics and Electromagnetism together with calc) --> linear alg --> ?????

Does it look good so far? Would you change anything about the order I will be learning? Any books you would recommend for any of those subjects??

It's a long road until im finished with linear alg so I'll ask about what I should do when trying to go further when I actually reach that point.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Discrete Mathematics is useful to any CS major.

Comment: What books you should read may partly depend on your level of ability in  math, and what an acceptable level of effort would be for you. It's not always easy to evaluate oneself in this way, but you might get more targeted answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Study Order for high school math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57472/study-order-for-high-school-math)

Answer (score 1):

What I would really suggest you is to follow the online courses from MIT, Standford and other faculties.

For the first two years the majority of courses are online and you just need to schedule one lesson at day from YouTube to emulate a real college experience. 
I post you some links, you should be able to find the others.
[Linear Algebra](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/)
[Calculus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jbIQW0gkgxo&list=PL2F4E0D8825971542)

You could just take a classic program for the first two years and follow the lessons from YouTube. Classical courses are Linear Algebra, Calculus, Physics 1 and 2 and then maybe something in Computer Science 
Good luck